# Relational Overriding Symbol from Rodin IDE

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I'm looking for a way to write the following relational overriding symbol. The symbol is used in the Rodin IDE.

Thank you!!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! With the help of chatGPT and some testing/modifying it slightly, I am now using something that is close enough! I am using the following command:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\override}{\mathrel{\lhd\mkern-8mu-}}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Comment: How did you do this via chatGPT by the way? I thought images were difficult on that, did you post a link to this question and it gave you that code output? Genuinely curious as that is useful if it helped you find that image that fast

Comment: @JamesT 
I described the symbol that I wanted to use. Here are the prompts that I asked it. I didn't expect it to work, but even though my description wasn't the best it worked very well!                                      "The relational override symbol used in the Rodin IDE is an empty triangle pointing to the left with an offset minus sign vertically centered to the right"                   and                     "Can you make the code move the minus sign slightly more to the left?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, glad it helped and thanks for the description!

Comment: @JamesT No problem and anytime! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use proper relational symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\override}{%
  \vartriangleleft % a relation
  \mathrel{\mspace{-9mu}}% back up
  \relbar
}

\begin{document}

$r\override\{(a,3),(c,4)\}$

\end{document}
```

Note that `\lhd` is a binary operation symbol, not a relation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know it isn't the most commonly used symbol but that is what is used in my course. I also know that it is technically not the right triangle but I was looking for something that looked close enough. :) 
(Thank you for providing more context and alternatives!)